# Create a set_difference vector from two maps

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Currently I am getting the set difference of two maps and then iterating through the resulting map.

Ideally I want to create a vector of the difference instead of a map. That way I iterate more efficiently.

```
typedef std::map<int, Info> RegistrationMap;

RegistrationMap redundantRegs;
std::set_difference(map1.begin(), map1.end(), map2.begin(), map2.end(), 
std::inserter(redundantRegs, redundantRegs.begin()),
    [](const std::pair<int, Info> &p1, const std::pair<int, Info> &p2 {return p1.first < p2.first;});

for (auto reg : redundantRegs)
{
    map2[hiu.first].Status = "delete";
}
```

How would you create a vector of the set difference instead? Can this be done within the set_difference function?

I'm looking for the most efficient way possible of getting the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::set_difference` can write its output to any output iterator, so there is no problem with writing the output into a vector:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, Info>> redundantRegs;
std::set_difference(map1.begin(), map1.end(), map2.begin(), map2.end(),
                    std::back_inserter(redundantRegs),
                    ...);
```

(Note: In your comparator, change `std::pair<int, Info>` to `std::pair<const int, Info>` to avoid unnecessary copies.)

Comment: Even better use `RegistrationMap::value_type` instead of using `std::pair` explicitly

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::set_difference` but instead of `std::inserter` you better use `std::back_inserter` as that is most efficient on `std::vector`, and create `std::vector` accordingly:

```
std::vector<RegistrationMap::value_type> redundantRegs;;
std::set_difference(map1.begin(), map1.end(), map2.begin(), map2.end(), 
                    std::back_inserter(redundantRegs) );
```

Note: in the way you wrote it you do not need to write comparator explicitly, default one will work just fine. If you do not use default one, you better get it from the `std::map` using `std::map::value_comp()` instead of writing it explicitly as sorting criteria must match for map and `std::set_difference`:

```
std::set_difference(map1.begin(), map1.end(), map2.begin(), map2.end(), 
                    std::back_inserter(redundantRegs),
                    map1.value_comp() );
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/lrYI61)